# jQuery is unable to find the element, in IE 7 document mode

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to make some edits to a site for a client of mine. This is the selector I am trying.

This is the site I am trying to edit. http://www.lederne.dk/kampagner/faglig_organisation/forside.htm

```
jQuery("DIV#ctl01_uiBreadCrumbServerDiv + DIV > DIV:first-child + DIV > DIV:first-child > DIV:first-child")
```

This does not work in the default settings on the page in IE9. However, if I now change the document mode to IE9(originally it is IE7), the selector works.

I have done quite some search to see what might be wrong, but nothing seems to help.

You can use this code to add jquery to this page

```
var s=document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('src','http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js');
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);
```

Comment: @ArunPJohny included the link to the HTML

Comment: @Amit: Which element are you wanting to select? If I'm reading the selector correctly, this should be pointing to the `div` with class `cntLeft` descending from the `div` with class `navigation` (or should this select something else)?

Comment: @pete This would select the div with class `content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
jQuery("DIV#ctl01_uiBreadCrumbServerDiv + DIV > DIV:eq(1) > DIV:eq(0) > DIV:eq(0)").addClass("gotit")
```

will solve your problem

Comment: This does solve the issue, however, I am more concerned as to why the selector I used isn't working on ie7?

Comment: It looks like a possible bug in the jQuery selector (sizzle), the error occurs when the adjacent sibling selector is used before the :first-child selctor. Here is a demo to show this problem http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bxEJe/